# Mass DM command isnt working (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

This is the code I use to mass dm is the following:

```
  if (message.content === 'tdm'){

  message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => { // Looping through each member of the guild.
    // Trying to send a message to the member.
    // This method might fail because of the member's privacy settings, so we're using .catch
    member.send("test").catch(e => console.error(`Couldn't DM member ${member.user.tag}`));
  });
}
```

I tried the command, and ask my members if they got a message from the bot, and they all said no. Am I doing something wrong? It worked 2 weeks prior.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: There no errors in the console, The only thing that console logged was the user that it couldnt dm and that was a bot named "sx4"

Comment: Are you using `Discord` v12? What exactly is stored in `member` ? I am 99% sure that it isn't a discord-member itself.

Comment: Try replacing `message.guild.members.cache.forEach()` with `(await message.guild.members.fetch()).each()`. You will also need to make the surrounding function asynchronous.

Comment: I'm using discordv12

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `message.guild.members.cache.forEach()` to `(await message.guild.members.fetch()).each()`.

[`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) is used instead of `.cache` to ensure all the members get fetched instead of just the ones in cache.

[`.each()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each) is used instead of `.forEach` because `message.guild.members.fetch()` returns a Discord collection ([`Discord.Collection()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)), not an array.

```js
if (message.content === 'tdm'){
  (await message.guild.members.fetch()).each(member => { // Looping through each member of the guild.
    // Trying to send a message to the member.
    // This method might fail because of the member's privacy settings, so we're using .catch
    member.send("test").catch(e => console.error(`Couldn't DM member ${member.user.tag}`));
  });
}
```

Comment: An Error logged in the console saying: `(await message.guild.members.fetch()).each(member => { // Looping through each member of the guild.
           ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`, I don't understand what this means

Comment: @11tracy Make sure the message event handler function is asynchronous.

Comment: Ok It worked but the bot didn't DM me, It did log the users it didn't dm

Comment: @11tracy Sorry but I don't quite understand what the issue is. Is the only problem that it didn't DM you?